# Sum of rows with join

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: MySQL problem]

This is the current table layout.

- There are 3 legs
- Each leg has 2 points, where `is_start` = 1 is the start of the leg, and `is_start` is the end of the leg.
- When the user check in at a point, a entry in `points_user` are created.

In this application you have multiple legs which has 2 points where one marks the start of the leg, where the other marks the end of the leg. So the sum of User's (with id = 2) Leg (with id= 1) is `points_users`.`created` where `points_users`.`leg_id` = 1 and `points_users`.`user_id` = 2 and `points_users`.`is_start` = 0 minus points_users where is_start = 1 (and the other parameters stay the same). And that's for just one leg.

What I would like is to sum all the time differences for each leg, we get the data like this:

```
| User.id | User.name | total_time |
| 1       | John      | 129934     |
```

Anyone know how I can join these tables and sum it up grouped by user?

(No, this is not homework)

As far as I got:

```
SELECT
( `end_time` - `start_time` ) AS `diff`
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`p1`.`created`)) AS `start_time`
    FROM `points_users` AS `pu1`
    LEFT JOIN `points` AS `p1` ON `pu1`.`point_id` = `p1`.`id`
    WHERE `p1`.`is_start` = 1
) AS `start_time`,
(
    SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`pu2`.`created`)) AS `end_time`
    FROM `points_users` AS `pu2`
    LEFT JOIN `points` AS `p2` ON `pu2`.`point_id` = `p2`.`id`
    WHERE `p2`.`is_start` = 0
) AS `end_time`
```

Comment: Homework? Sounds like it! Also, could you please specify the primary keys of your tables? That'd help understand how to get to the "correct" solution.

Comment: And what have you tried, again?

Comment: @Romain: Hehe, wish I was that young again..

Comment: @Adrian: http://pastebin.com/ZZ6BQv2G This is as far as I got. I tried several times to join in user and group by user_id without success. Not that far, as you can see..

Comment: I just looked at your paste via another connection.  It shows `is_start` as a field on a `points` table, but the schema implied in your question has it on `points_users`.  Which is it?

Comment: @fortysixandtwo You are in StackOverflow for over a year now, you should know you are supposed to paste the code here, not somewhere else. Just did that for you.

Comment: Is there a reason you did an outer join between `points_users` and `points`?  Is it possible that the point referenced in `points_users` doesn't exist in `points`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select users.user_id,
    users.user_name,
    SUM(timeDuration) totalTime
from users
join (
    select 
        pStart.User_id,
        pStart.leg_id,
        (pEnd.created - pStart.created) timeDuration                
    from (select pu.user_id,  pu.leg_id,  pu.created
        from points_users pu
        join points p on  pu.id = p.point_id and pu.leg_id = p.leg_id
        where p.is_start = 1 ) pStart
    join  (select pu.user_id, pu.leg_id,  pu.created
        from points_users pu
        join points p on  pu.id = p.point_id and pu.leg_id = p.leg_id
        where p.is_start = 0 ) pEnd
    on      pStart.user_id = pEnd.user_id
    and     pStart.leg_id = pEnd.leg_id
    ) tt
on users.user_id = tt.user_id
group by users.user_id, users.user_name
```

Subquery gets the time duration for each user/leg, and main query then sums them for all the legs of each user.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Added the `points` table now that I can see your attempt at a query.

The simplest way is to join `points_users` to itself:

```
select leg_start.user_id, sum(leg_end.created - leg_start.created)
from points_users leg_start
join points_users leg_end on leg_start.user_id = leg_end.user_id
    and leg_start.leg_id = leg_end.leg_id
join points point_start on leg_start.point_id = point_start.id
join points point_end on leg_end.point_id = point_end.id
where point_start.is_start = 1 and point_end.is_start = 0
group by leg_start.user_id
```

Some people prefer to put those `is_start` filters in the join condition, but since it's an inner join that's mainly just a point of style.  If it were an outer join, then moving them from the WHERE to the JOIN could have an effect on the results.